# Add and remove child component

Tags: angularjs

I have a `pageTab` component that has multiple children.  Each child component registers themselves with the parents to allow the parent to show and hide them when the relevant tab is clicked.

My issue is that I can make the contents of the child show and hide via `ng-if` but I am unsure how to make the component itself show and hide.  Can anyone help?

Example of problem:

```
<page-tab title="Vehicle"><!-- Correctly shown, has contents --></page-tab>
<page-tab title="Reminders"><!-- Inner contents hidden, but page-tab still visible --></page-tab>
```

This creates whitespace on the page which is an issue, so I would ideally like to have an `ng-if` on the `page-tab` component itself, or somehow let the parent remove it.

Here is how it is all stitched together:

Parent `page` component

```
registerPage(tab: IPageTab) {
    this.tabs.push(tab);

    if (this.tabs.length == 1) {
        this.showTab(tab);
    }
}

showTab(tab: IPageTab) {
    this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
        tab.controller.hide();
    });

    tab.controller.show();
}
```

page.html

```
<div><h1 flex>{{$ctrl.title}}</h1></div>

<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="$ctrl.selectedPage">
    <md-nav-item ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.tabs"
                 name="{{tab.title}}"
                 md-nav-click="$ctrl.showTab(tab)">
        {{tab.title}}
    </md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>

<div flex layout="column" ng-transclude></div>
```

PageTab component

```
$onInit() {
    this.parent.registerPage({
        title: this.title,
        controller: this,
        url: ""
    });
}

show() {
    this.visible = true;
    this.$element.removeClass("hidden");
}

hide() {
    this.visible = false;
    this.$element.addClass("hidden");
}
```

pageTab.html

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.visible" ng-transclude></div>
```

This is how it is actually used in practice

```
<page title="Maintenance">
    <page-tab title="Vehicles">
        <maintenance-vehicle-list flex></maintenance-vehicle-list>
    </page-tab>

    <page-tab title="Reminders">
        <task-schedule-list flex></task-schedule-list>
    </page-tab>
</page>
```

**Update** as per Petr's answer I now use `$element.addClass` and `$element.removeClass` to hide the inner contents, but ideally id like to dyncamilly add an `ng-if` to the root child component, rather than show & hide via css / class.

Comment: you can hide elements using $element.addClass('my-display-none'), you can use ng-if directly (though seems you dont want to), you can add ng-if dynamically and recompile elements, you can manage elements manually, ...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thanks, I actually use `$element.addClass` at the moment, how would I go about adding ng-if dynamically? Thanks